# Levels in R from vector

Tags: r

`lvl` is a list containing character vectors.

```
> lvl["Region"]
$Region
[1] "USA"   "LONDON"    "SINGAPORE"

> factor("USA", levels=lvl["Region"])
[1] <NA>
Levels: c("USA", "LONDON", "SINGAPORE")

> factor("USA", levels=c("USA", "LONDON", "SINGAPORE"))
[1] USA
Levels: USA LONDON SINGAPORE
```

The third statement is as expected. Why does the second statement create only 1 level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like 'lvl' is a `list`.

The `lvl['Region']` is still a `list` with a single element

```
is.list(lvl['Region'])
#[1] TRUE
```

and `levels` argument in `factor` take `vector`.  In order to extract the `vector`, use `[[`

```
factor("USA", levels=lvl[["Region"]])
#[1] USA
#Levels: USA LONDON SINGAPORE
```

#### data

```
lvl <- list(Region = c("USA", "LONDON", "SINGAPORE"))
```